# xcode - Capitalise Label Output

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uilabel, programmatically-created

I'm pretty new to xcode - so please bear with me!

I'm outputting information from a database to UILabels with information like Name, Region, etc (all good, so far). However - there is a column of text in the database which is all in lowercase (ie *flat area to the left*)...

The lowercase text looks pretty sucky when it's loaded into the app - so without going into the database and changing all 5000 entries, is there a way to force capitalization programmatically (as is possible in CSS, for example)?

For reference, I'm using the following code in the header file:

```
IBOutlet UILabel *lblfeatures;
```

Then in the implementation file:

```
lblfeatures.text = [self.passedDict objectForKey:@"Feature"];
```

And linked up through the connections inspector.

Thanks so much :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to do something like:

```
lblfeatures.text = [[self.passedDict objectForKey:@"Feature"] capitalizedString];
```

There are more methods for capitalization described in https://developer.apple.com/library/Mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/capitalizedString.

Comment: oh man - it was that simple! Thanks a lot. I find the Mac Developer Library so difficult to plough through - but we're getting there...

Comment: @Dave yeah it can be confusing at first, but once you learn how to navigate you see how excellent the documentation is. Especially compared to some other platforms.

Answer (score 0):

you should use this :

```
lblfeatures.text= [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"(%@)", [self.passedDict objectForKey:@"Feature"]]capitalizedString];
```